# It is possible to take a photo centered to the north with dji drone?

Tags: photo, dji-sdk

Is it possible to take a photo centered to the north with dji drone?
for example I would take a series of photos to create a 360 views and I would like  that the first of these photos is centered to the north.
It's doable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Yes.

Using the mobile SDK, you can control the aircraft programmatically.
This could be you flying the aircraft facing north and running a special panorama mission or even automating the flying so the aircraft goes where you want as well.

To give you more details, I would need a more precise question.

In the mean time, check out [developer.dji.com](http://developer.dji.com) for all info on the MobileSDK (Android and iOS)

Comment: Thanks Arnaud ! I have a ViewController with the live video and I created a Start button who launches the mission on the actual position of the aircraft. I would create an other button (Prepare) who places the aircraft at an altitude of 100m and with the head oriented to the north.